# Zoom to my Location in Microsoft Power Apps

Tags: bing-maps, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I can add my location to a PowerApps Map Canvas app, it appears as a pulsating blue dot on the right place.

It would be great if the map canvas could zoom / fly to this position, after the GPS receiver has found the first signal.

Is there any solution in PowerApps for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the zooming other than hard coding this to a value, but for centering you could possible use Power FX and the Location values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-platform/power-fx/reference/signals#location This retrieves the users GPS location. You could then pass those into the current Latitude/Longitude fields of the map component.

This looks related: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-add-GPS-to-get-current-Location-in-mobile-app/td-p/752881